# Return first record per group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I grab an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which contains records where each record is the **first** `author` for each `book`.

```
# Models
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors_books
end

class AuthorsBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end

class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors_books
end
```

`@author_books = AuthorsBooks.all`

Example rows/records returned from `@author_books.all`

```
author_id    book_id
   3           1
   2           1
   3           1
   4           1
   1           2
   1           3
   2           4
   3           4
```

Now I want to grab only the **first** `author` per `book`:

Should return this:

```
author_id    book_id
   3           1
   1           2
   1           3
   2           4
```

Comment: @author_books is the result you get sorted based on id of AuthorBooks table. Do you want the first author per book created then? I mean based on created_at time of AuthorBooks record.

Comment: define first author?

Comment: May be this is what you want... `AuthorsBooks.all.group_by(&:book_id).collect{|k,v| v.first}`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yes, please post answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Glad that I can be of help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# returns an array of active record objects
ary_authorbook_objs = AuthorsBook.all.group_by(&:book_id).collect{|k,v| v.first}

# transforms that array of active record objects into one ActiveRecord::Relation object
active_relation_object = AuthorsBook.where(id: ary_authorbook_objs.map(&:id))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `inject`:

```
AuthorsBook.all
           .inject({}){|h, k| h[k.book_id] = k unless h.key? k.book_id; h}
           .values
```

Comment: Is it possible to return active record objects? I notice that your method returns a hash which contains only the `author_id` of the first `author` per group.  If possible I would like to have actual objects per those returned records as opposed to key/value pairs.

Comment: unfortunately your solution does not appear to work for our purposes.  Your solution is not grabbing the first record per group.  Instead, your solution is grabbing the minimum author_id per group.  We are trying to grab the actual first record per group (doesn't matter if that first record happens to have the minimum author_id or not). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The real world problem that we are applying this to: it is first sorted appropriately. So since we know that it is sorted how we want it to be, we want to grab the first one per group.